# DataGridView и отображение дополнительного поля

Tags: access, .net, c#

К DataGridView подключена для отображения определенная таблица базы данных, нужно добавить одно поле из другой таблицы, при этом чтоб была возможность редактирования данных первой таблицы.

Есть реализация с помощью кода, но в результате не обновляются данные после редактирования, то есть реддактирование не реализуется:

( в краце в бд две связанных таблицы Students,Priveleges )

```
OleDbConnection sqlconn = new OleDbConnection ("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Hostel.mdb");
    sqlconn.Open();
    OleDbDataAdapter a = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT [Student code], SNP, [Birth Year], Gender, Address, [Group], Priveleges.[Privelege type], Passport, Room, [Colonize Date] FROM Students , Priveleges WHERE Students.[Privelege code] = Priveleges.[Privelege code]", sqlconn);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    a.Fill(dt);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    sqlconn.Close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Могу предложить ещё такое решение. Колонка, которая берётся их таблицы привилегий, редактируется через ComboBox, которому в качестве источника данных передаётся таблица привилегий. У него задаётся DisplayMember и ValueMember так, чтобы редактировался идентификатор привилегии, а отображалось её название. Эта колонка должна быть связана с полем Students.[Privelege code]

Answer (score 0):

Реализовывается через базу.
Пишется view для чтения и процедура для сохранения. Потом командами подсоединить к DataSource